# Binding a DataTable to a DataView

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I have a DataTable called tblManual which is populated with data, now I'm trying to bind this to a DataView called DataView1. I am trying this:

```
DataView1.DataSource = tblManual;
DataView1.DataBind();
```

but when DataView1 displays on the web page it just shows up as blank, I am not getting any errors though, I have also confirmed that there is data in tblManual.

the code for DataView1 is in asp

```
<dx:ASPxDataView ID="DataView1" runat="server" EnableTheming="True" Layout="Flow" Theme="Moderno">
        <PagerSettings ShowNumericButtons="False"></PagerSettings>
    </dx:ASPxDataView>
```

here is tblManual showing it contains data
[image]

Comment: Can you post the markup for `DataView1`?

Comment: What you have these two statements, do they execute? check if you are getting any exception which they get executed

Comment: show your full code of DataView?

Comment: Are you sure that tblManual has data?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort your column in a datatable you can use this code

```
DataView dvData = new DataView(Yourdatatable);
dvData.Sort = "city";
GridView1.DataSource = dvData;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: OP's question asks nothing about sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<dx:GridViewDataColumn>`, set `FieldName` parameters like your DataSource's field names, here is an example:

```
<dx:ASPxDataView ID="DataView1" runat="server" EnableTheming="True" Layout="Flow" Theme="Moderno">
  <Columns>
    <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="Name" />
    <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="Region" />
    <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="Type" />
    <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="Price" />          
  </Columns>
  <PagerSettings ShowNumericButtons="False"></PagerSettings>
</dx:ASPxDataView>
```

Comment: when I try to add a GridViewDataColumn I get it is not a known element error. I only have ASPxGridView, GridView, ASPxGridViewExporter and ASPxGridViewTemplateReplacement in my toolbox.